# How to create instance for IDictionary<int, string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have my model like,

```
public IDictionary<int, string> QuestionSetList { get; set; }
```

i cannot use this QuestionSetList in my controller, when it executes, it throws a NullReferenceException, saying: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
i have my code like,

```
model.QuestionSetList.Add(QuestionSetNo,QuestionSetTopic);
```

Kindly tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Might be stating the obvious, but are `model`, `QuestionSetList`, `QuestionSetNo` or `QuestionSetTopic` null?

Comment: QuestionSetNo will obviously not be null, as it is a non-nullable type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't instantiate an interface because an interface is nothing but a *contract*. It does not have any *implementation*.

You need to instantiate a type that implements the interface. In this case, you can use a `Dictionary<int, string>` which implements `IDictionary<int, string>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate your variable which holds your Dictionary. That's why you get a NullReferenceException.

Try the follwoing.

```
private IDictionary<int, string> _questionSetList;
public IDictionary<int, string> QuestionSetList 
{ 
  get
  {
    if (_questionSetList == null)
    {
      _questionSetList = Dictionary<int, string>();
    }
    return _questionSetList;
  }
  set
  {
    _questionSetList = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what the code in your answer illustrates. Dumping code might help OP _now_, but they nor future visitors won't learn anything from copy-pasteable code.

Comment: @user743414 That's not the point. A good answer doesn't necessarily need to provide working code, but it absolutely has to explain conceptually what was broken.

Comment: That code never throws a NullReferenceException when accessing through the getter.